# Problems with hover CSS

Tags: css, hover, hide, element, show

I would like to show an img when i hover over another but nothing is happening. Any advice on what i can do to change the code

```
**HTML**
 <div id="container-collection">

   <img class="clothes1" src="Images/smallest/JPEG/IMG_3148.jpg">

   <img class="closeup1" src="Images/Smaller/bigger ones/JPEG/IMG_3148_1.jpg">

 </div>

**CSS**

img.closeup1{
    display: none;
}

img.closeup1:hover clothes1 {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @minitech said, you need to properly combine the controlled element selector with the `:hover` owner.

I'd go for something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container-collection">
    <div class="clothes1-wrap">
        <img class="clothes1" src="Images/smallest/JPEG/IMG_3148.jpg">
        <img class="closeup1" src="Images/Smaller/bigger ones/JPEG/IMG_3148_1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.closeup1 {
    display: none;
}

.clothes1-wrap:hover .closeup1 {
    display: block;
}
```

For me, this looks a little bit cleaner, plus you can add elements between `img`s.

Comment: thanks very much, that sorted it. Been messing about with it for hours.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're missing a `.` to select a class. It should be `.clothes1`.
2. You're missing a combinator; `.clothes1` is not a descendant of `.closeup1`. However, unfortunately, there doesn't yet exist a combinator for "previous sibling". In CSS4, there will be, but not now.

If shuffling the order is okay (you may be able to correct the positioning change with some fancy CSS), you can do this:

```
<div id="container-collection">

    <img class="closeup1" src="Images/Smaller/bigger ones/JPEG/IMG_3148_1.jpg">

    <img class="clothes1" src="Images/smallest/JPEG/IMG_3148.jpg">

</div>
```

```css
img.clothes1 {
    display: none;
}

img.closeup1:hover + .clothes1 {
    display: block;
}
```